# Finding out the maximum length of input number

Tags: c

I'm trying to findout the maximum length of input number. For example,

```
input: 1101  ouput: 4   input: 10        output: 5
       11                      01110  
       01                      01
       1                       1
```

However, I have no idea how to store the input when it terminate a line. I try to use getchar to create a loop and it is a '\n' it record a value but when it loop again the value will change. Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

```
int c;
int l;
while (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c != '\n') {
     l ++;
 } else {
 l = 0;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, and please read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.  How about showing some code you have tried?  We are not mind readers.

Comment: Do you want them to be arguments passed into a program? Are you reading from a file? Where are the numbers that you want to process? Edit : Yea, what @OldProgrammer said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int c;
    int l=0;
    int maximum_length=-1;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != '\n') {
            l++;
        } else {
            if(maximum_length < l)
                maximum_length = l;
            l = 0;
        }
    }
```